# difference between NSObject and Struct

Tags: struct, swift, ios8

I want to know the difference between the `NSObject` and `struct`..Following example will explain both cases

In `struct`

```
struct UserDetails{
    var userName:String
    var userID:String
    var userAge:String
    func userDescription()->String{
        return "name " + userName + "age " + userAge
    }
}
```

In `NSObject` Class

```
class UserDetails: NSObject {
    var userName:String?
    var userID:String?
    var userAge:String?
    func userDescription()->String{
        return "name " + userName! + "age " + userAge!
    }
}
```

Can you anyone please tell me where I have to use `NSObject` class, where I have to use `struct`..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes and structs in Swift are much closer than in many languages. Both can have properties, method, initializers, subscripts, can conform to protocols, and can be extended. However, only classes can take advantage of inheritance and use deinitializers, and because classes are used by reference, you can have more than one reference to a particular instance.

Structs are used throughout Swift -- arrays, dictionaries, everything optional, and more are built on the `struct` type, so performance should be very high. You can use `struct` whenever you don't need the inheritance or multiple references that classes provide.

Comment: which one will take more memory ?

Comment: `Optional` is actually an `enum`, but they are similar to `struct`s

Answer (score 6):

1) Structs are passed by value, Class instances by reference
2) Classes can be subclassed, Structs can't.

Whether or not the Class is a subclass of NSObject is (mostly) irrelevant. You could equally have said:

```
class UserDetails {
    var userName:String?
    var userID:String?
    var userAge:String?
    func userDescription()->String{
        return "name " + userName! + "age " + userAge!
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there's much in it - it's really a design decision. If you are ever going to need to subclass, Class is the way to go. If you know you will never subclass, you can use a Struct.

Comment: Neither. Both have good and bad aspects for performance, depending on the situation (classes require reference counting, pointer indirection, and memory allocation, but structs require making copies).

Comment: @Grimxn in other words, if you pass a lot of structs around all over the place they will be much MUCH slower than objects and use significantly more RAM. If you do not pass them around much, then structs will be faster and use less RAM. Basically, if your code is too slow or uses too much memory you should consider testing the other.

Comment: @newacct I'm confused by your usage "you can only manipulate them through pointers", since (despite the underlying representation) one of the major themes of Swift is to remove the concept of pointers from developers' semantics when using the language.

Comment: @Grimxn: They are pointers, no matter what you call them. Pointer = something that points to something. "Reference type" means a type whose values are references (pointers).